# How to test Functions with TcUnit in TwinCAT3?

Tags: testing, twincat

I want to write tests for my functions. I came across a framework for testing in TwinCAT 3, but I didn't find any examples of how to properly test functions there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a convenient example of the implementation of testing of a function on the [user introduction page](https://tcunit.org/introduction-user-guide/) where a Function Block 'FB_Sum' is run through some basic tests (As usual Jakob has it under control ).

In order to apply this example to a Function rather than a Function Block all that is needed is to generate this object as a Function. The FB version applies no additional functionality beyond that which is available as a Function (i.e. there are no methods/properties/internal memory spaces).

Updating `METHOD TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour` with the following changes allows you to run a test on `f_Sum`:

```
METHOD TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour
VAR
    Result : UINT;
    ExpectedSum : UINT := 4;
END_VAR

TEST('TwoPlusTwoEqualsFour');

Result := f_Sum( one := 2, two := 2);

AssertEquals(Expected := ExpectedSum,
             Actual := Result,
             Message := 'The calculation is not correct');

TEST_FINISHED();
```

---

```
FUNCTION f_Sum
VAR_INPUT
    one : UINT;
    two : UINT;
END_VAR

f_Sum := one + two;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have now added this question to the F.A.Q of TcUnit: https://tcunit.org/frequently-asked-questions/?Display_FAQ=1040